# sweet.js how to match function statement with infix

Tags: javascript, sweet.js

I can't seem to get a match

```
let function = macro {
  case infix {$name:ident $[=] | _ ($params ...) { $body ...} } => {
    return #{
      $name = function $name ($params ...) {
        console.log($name.name);
        $body ...
      }
    }
  }
}
var add = function (x, y){
  return x+y;
}

SyntaxError: [macro] Macro `function` could not be matched with `() {} ...`
11: var add = function (x, y){
              ^
```

Macro works fine without var.

I'm aware that 1 non-expr term is allowed in expression position
but `var $name:ident $[=]` doesn't work.

If this is impossible with infix is there another way to match a function statement and capture the name of the function?

Answer (score 1):

It seems I needed to see my problem from a wider scope. As @timdisney explains above,

`var xxx = function () {}`

requires a **var** macro, not a **function** macro.

```
// log function calls

    let var = macro {
      case {
        $_ $id = function ($params ...) {$body ...}
      } => {
        return #{
          var $id = function $id ($params ...) { 
            console.log($id.name);
            $body ...
          }
        };
      }
      case { $_ } => { return #{var}; }
    };
```

The second case is a catch-all that returns function unchanged. It's called an identity rule.

Answer (score 0):

The interaction of infix and `var` is special. For hygiene reasons infix macros can only see back to the `=` in a var initializer. I've been thinking about how we could ease up that restriction but nothing concrete yet.

To solve you problem here though you might be able to make a `var` macro that does the thing you want.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I found the solution while scouring some of the examples. Simple. Yet a revelation on how to approach macros in the future.